# score calculation takes too long: avoid for loops - python

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, product, sparse-matrix

I am new to python and I need your kindly help.

I have three matrices, in particular:

- Matrix M (class of the matrix: scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix), dimensions: N x C;
- Matrix G (class of the matrix: numpy.ndarray), dimensions: C x T;
- Matrix L (class of the matrix: numpy.ndarray), dimensions: T x N.

Where: N = 10000, C = 1000, T = 20.

I would like to calculate, this score:

[image]

I tried by using two `for` loops , one for the `i`-index and one for `c`. Furthermore, I used a `dot` product for obtaining the last sum in the equation. But my implementation requires too much times for giving the result.

This is what I implemented:

```
    score = 0.0
    for i in range(N): 
        for c in range(C):
            Mic = M[i,c]
            score += np.outer(Mic,(np.dot(L[:,i],G[c,:])))
```

Is there a way to avoid the two `for` loops?

Thank you in advance!

Best

Comment: I'm not surprised.  Iteration like this on `numpy` arrays is slow, and iteration on a sparse one even slower.  `csc` matrices are optimized for matrix multiplication (`dot)`, and even requires a significant degree of sparsity (only a few nonzero values relative to the total shape).  Why are you using `outer` when `Mic` is a scalar value (that might be 0)?

Comment: For a start, `G.dot(L)` or even `G@L` should give a (C,N) shape array.  I was going to suggest  `M.dot(G@L)`, but that's (N,N), while you want its diagonal, or rather its trace.

Comment: I will try this solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `score = np.einsum("ic,ti,ct->", M, L, G)`

**EDIT1**

By the way, in your case, `score = np.sum(np.diag(M @ G @ L))` (in PYTHON3 starting from version 3.5, you can use the semantics of the `@` operator for `matmul` function) is faster than `einsum` (especially in `np.trace((L @ M) @ G )` due to efficient use of memory, maybe @hpaulj meant this in his comment). But `einsum` is easier to use for complex tensor products (to encode with `einsum` I used your math expression directly without thinking about optimization).

Generally, using `for` with `numpy` results in a dramatic slowdown in computation speed (think "vectorize your computations" in the case of `numpy`).

Comment: I don't think `einsum` works with `M`.  With `M.A` yes, if there is enough memory.

Comment: I have no memory problems (float64 for all M,L,G) on my laptop with 8GB of RAM.

Comment: Many thanks! And if I would like also to apply a log on the result of last sum (so a log of the dot product), is there a way to continue to use `einsum`? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, of course, you can use `einsum` to calculate the dot product if you really need to do this. Do you mean `log` as a mathematical function?  By the way, in "staskoverflow" to express your gratitude, you can just accept answer and/or click on "this answer is usefull" uparrow on the left side of the answer (or comment).

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering how I can use `einsum` if I would like to add a `log` on the result of the last sum in the score equation... So, the score will become: sum_i(sum_c M_ic * log (sum_t L_ti * G_ct)). Thank you in advance!

Comment: This should work: score = np.sum(np.diag(M @ np.log(G @ L)))

Comment: For `sum_i(sum_c M_ic * log (sum_t L_ti * G_ct))`, the use of `einsum` is not a good solution (directly following your expression that is: `np.einsum("ic,ci->",M, np.log(np.einsum("ti,ct->ci",L,G)))`). You have a good solution. One comment: `np.sum(np.diag(A))` for a square matrix `A` is the same as `np.trace(A)`.